# Elastic Beanstalk purging Varnish across instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, varnish, elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I’m a little stuck with how best to clear Varnish across all my instances on Elastic Beanstalk - unfortunately I’m not most knowledgeable with AWS.

I would like to keep things simple regarding the set up so I opted to have a Varnish cache on each server rather than separate Varnish servers.

Now if I have site which can clear the cache, it would go through the load balancer and only hit one server. From there I guess I could then hit the reach of my instances but at that stage I have no idea what the IPs are each instances are. So would I need to use AWS Cli to grab all instances then trigger a clear on each? Or is there a way when a certain URL is called (maybe with header) that it reaches all instances behind that load balancer.

I would really appreciate some guidance on this.

Below is my config, one thing that might look a little weird is the X-Purge-Token - I’ve decided it might make sense if a request comes from the load balancer or another instances check the header for token before allowing purge. I originally planned to use X-Forwarded-For but because IPs change I wasn’t sure the best route for this.

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root

  - option_name: APP_ENV
    value: placeholder
  - option_name: APP_KEY
    value: placeholder

packages:
  yum:
    varnish: []

files:
  "/etc/varnish/default.vcl":
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      backend default {
          .host = "127.0.0.1";
          .port = "8080";
      }

      acl elb {
        "172.31.0.0"/20;
        "172.31.16.0"/20;
        "172.31.32.0"/20;
      }

      acl purge {
        "localhost";
        "127.0.0.1";
        "::1";
        "86.19.111.22";
        "213.106.111.22";
      }

      sub vcl_recv {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {

          set req.http.xff = regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, "^[^,]+.?.?(.*)$", "\1");

          if(client.ip ~ elb) {
            if (req.http.X-Purge-Token == "tFjn3MnrunWzi49x") {
              return (lookup);
            }
          } else {
            if (client.ip ~ purge) {
              return (lookup);
            }
          }

           error 405 "Not allowed.";
        }
        if (!(req.url ~ "(preview=true|wp-login|wp-admin)")) {
          unset req.http.cookie;
        }
      }

      sub vcl_fetch {
        if (beresp.ttl == 120s) {
          set beresp.ttl = 24h;
        }

        if (!(req.url ~ "(preview=true|wp-login|wp-admin)")) {
          unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        }
      }

      sub vcl_hit {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
          if(req.http.X-Purge-Method == "regex") {
            ban("req.url ~ " + req.url + " && req.http.host ~ " + req.http.host);
          }
          purge;
          error 200 "Purged.";
        }
      }

      sub vcl_miss {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
          if(req.http.X-Purge-Method == "regex") {
            ban("req.url ~ " + req.url + " && req.http.host ~ " + req.http.host);
          }
          purge;
          error 200 "Purged.";
        }
      }



commands:
  001_update_composer:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update
  010_httpd.conf:
    command: "sed -i 's/Listen 8080/Listen 80/g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf"
  011_httpd.conf:
    command: "sed -i 's/Listen 80/Listen 8080/g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf"
  040_varnish:
    command: "sed -i 's/VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=6081/VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80/g' /etc/sysconfig/varnish"
  041_varnish:
    command: "sed -i 's/VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082/VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=2000/g' /etc/sysconfig/varnish"

container_commands:
   "1-storage-permissions":
      command: "mkdir -p public/content/uploads && chmod -R 755 public/content/uploads"
   "2-install-dependencies":
      command: "/usr/bin/composer.phar install"

services:
  sysvinit:
    varnish:
      enabled: true
      ensureRunning: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using the CLI is your best bet. Tag up your Elastic Beanstalk environments with appropriate tags which you can use to identify your EC2 instances. For example, an `EnvironmentName` and `ServiceName` tag.

Then you could do the following CLI call to get the private IP addresses of those instances which you then can use for sending individual purge requests to.

```sh
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --region eu-west-1 \
    --filter Name=tag:EnvironmentName,Values=production \
    --filter Name=tag:ServiceName,Values=cache \
    --query "Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress"
```

You would of course need to replace the values of the region, EnvironmentName and ServiceName so it fits your setup.